# how can I sort a fetchRequest by prefix matching a search string in coreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I have a coreData fetchRequest that filters results based on a searchString entered by the user.

I want the results to begin with the same prefix as the searchString rather than just beginning alphabetically or in any other order.

For example if my array is:

```
["apple", "banana", "cherry", "durian", "raspberry"]
```

and my searchString entered in the search bar is "r", I would like "raspberry" to be the first result returned followed by "cherry" and "durian"

For the above my predicate is:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "item.itemName CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchString)
```

At the moment my sortDescriptor is:

```
let prefixSort = ???
let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "item.itemName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
request.sortDescriptors = [prefixSort, nameSort]
```

Not sure how to enter the prefixSort so that the results will be sorted for the prefix being the searchString taking priority

Comment: You can create a NSSortDescriptor with a custom comparator, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssortdescriptor/1411607-init

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is a custom comparator compatible with a Core Data fetch?

Comment: I've just tried using one and it is not compatible with coreDdata fetch

Comment: @alionthego How did you solve this? I am also in search for a solution. Fetching all objects into array and then applying sort will be time-costly when there are say ~30K objects.

Comment: I ended up using: yourArray.filter { $0["property"]!.lowercased().prefix(searchString.count) == searchString.lowercased() to reduce results.  this was for a dictionary but can. easily adapt to array